# How to make AlertDialog.builder's negative button invisible?

Tags: android

I've got a problem.

I'm using AlertDialog.builder to create an alert box.

However I failed to disable/make the negative button invisible to the user.

I searched the API and cannot find a clue.

Any help on this issue is appreciated.

Thanks SOers.

EDIT:

Current situation is that the alertDialog has been displayed once with positive and negative button displayed.

After a few steps, the alertDialog will be reused to display another messages. However this time the negative button should be gone and with positive button sitting in the middle of the alertDialog.

Answer (score 0):

you can just **delete** this arguments on your builder:

```
.setNegativeButton
```

and don't forget to call

```
.setCancelable(false);
```

if you want to make the user can't canceling with back

---edit----

if you want to use it on the future, you should have some "flag" to activate it, and just put your setNegativeButton INSIDE an if arguments. example:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new onClickListener);
if(shouldAppear == true){
      builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener);
}
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

you can set the `shouldAppear = false` after `alert.show()` so it automatically hidden after shown once, or you can call it on other argument.

Comment: Yes, the negative button may be visible again in the future as the AlertDialog.builder is reused.

Comment: @BlackMaggie is it work or not? please give any feedback. thanks

Comment: Sorry, I had search google and SO and also found some code like yours but it cannot function as what I expected. Anyway thanks for your effort.